# how to apply zeroes to non-matching indices of filtered data

Tags: octave

I am learning octave, and I have a comparison made like so:

```
ma = [1,2,3,4,5];
indices = ma > 3;
```

The conditions filter 'ma', and the var 'indices' prints the indices matching the conditions, which looks like:

> [4, 5]

... but what I want is to use that result to return an array like this:

> [0,0,0,4,5];

Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
ma = [1,2,3,4,5];
ma(ma <= 3) = 0
```

Basically, just invert the condition and use it to set the values to zero.

Comment: thanks!  i'd not seen that particular syntax.  where can i refer to such approaches in the docs?

Comment: The part about using logical matrix (`ma <= 3`) as index is on the [logical values section](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Logical-Values.html). The rest is just [indexing operation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Index-Expressions.html).